# forEach для NodeList

Tags: javascript

Почему везде пишут, что NodeList не имеет метода forEach ( как у массива )?
Например здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Если взять такой код

```
<div class="one">One</div>
<div class="one">Two</div>
<div class="one">Three</div>
```

то для него forEach работает

```
 var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.one');
 var list = nodeList.forEach(function(x){
 console.log(x.innerHTML);
 }) // One, Two, Three
```

т.к. в *proto* NodeList forEach присутствует

Comment: Может быть имеют ввиду что его нет в каких то старых версиях JS? Может его добавили в новых версиях.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList - лучше всегда читать доки на английском. Потому что на других языках может быть устаревшие сведения.

Comment: Да, действительно в английской версии написано, что такой метод существует. Спасибо!